# Should we exclude any how do i pass exam X or prepare for certification y types of questions

Tags: discussion

One thing that I think will be important is to try and keep the Q&A on this site of high value. One of the lowest value types of questions that I know of are interview prep types of questions for tools like Quick Test Pro.

Do you think that these types of questions should be discouraged?

The sort of answers I would like to see are .. gain X experience, read Y or learn Z. Not here are the cheats to pass the exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would like to discourage that type of question. If we're building a site for experts, rather than expert fakers, we need to close irrelevant and low value questions quickly, or experts will leave.